# I need to use the "onchange" event inside @Html.RadioButton.[MVC]

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, dom-events

I need to use the `onchange` event inside @Html.RadioButton.[MVC]
I have a function  exp

```
 function FoncExamp() {
        if (document.ExpForm.K_T[0].checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("EK").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("YK").style.display = "none";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("EK").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("YK").style.display = "block";
        }
    }
```

I need to call this function on @html.radiobuttons

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { name = "ExpForm" }))
{
<div class="container well">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-md-2">EK @Html.RadioButton("K_T", "E_K")</label>
        <label class="col-md-2">YK @Html.RadioButton("K_T", "Y_K", new { @checked = true })</label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the onchange event to htmlAttributes

```
 <label class="col-md-2">EK @Html.RadioButton("K_T", "E_K", new { onchange = "FoncExamp(this)" })</label>
 <label class="col-md-2">YK @Html.RadioButton("K_T", "Y_K", new { @checked = true , onchange = "FoncExamp(this)"})</label>
```